# No se abre el menu desplegable

Tags: html, python, jquery, css, django

Estoy realizando una pagina en Django que tiene un menú desplegable. El problema que tengo es que al apretar en el icono no se abre el menú.

El video que use para realizar este menú fue el siguiente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEC4kqzNTnM&t

Dejo el código:

(ACTUALIZACIÓN DEL CODIGO)

el script del jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('icon').click(function(){
            $('ul').toggleClass('show')
        })
    })
```

nav.html:

```
<ul class="navbar-logo">
    <figure>
        <a href="{% url 'products:feed' %}" class="navbar-cont">
            <img src="{% static 'img/logo.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </a>
    </figure>
<ul class="marca-nav">
    {% for marca in marca_list %}
    <li>
        {% if marca.title != request.path|cut:"post/"|cut:'/' %}
        <a href="{% url 'products:marca' marca.title %}">
            {{ marca.title }}         
        </a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'products:marca' marca.title %}">
            {{ marca.title }}
        </a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<div class="navbar-menu">
    <label id="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

main.css:

```
.navbar-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#icon {
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 80px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
label.navbar-logo {
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}   
.marca-nav {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #2f3640;
    top: 12vh;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
}    
.marca-nav .show {
    left: 0;
}    
.marca-nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Si me recomiendan algún otro video para poder realizarlo seria de gran ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: En el selector `$('icon')` te faltó agregar `#` para que busque el elemento por ID: `$'#icon')`

Comment: @Triby sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @LucasLeone si pones un `console.log('nada')` dentro del click de lo muestra? Si es asi, si pones `$('ul').toggleClass('show')` fuera del `click`, te funciona?

Comment: Tampoco funciona, si lo saco del click aparece la clase show pero no hace nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al no poder ejecutar tu código en mi servidor, te hice un ejemplo de como hago yo para hacer aparecer y ocultar un contenido en especifico.

```js
    $(document).on("ready", function () {
       $(".nav").click(function () {
            $(".box").toggle();
        });
    })
```

```css
.nav {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .box {
        display: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;  
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    menú
</div>
<div class="box">
    box oculto
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

fíjate en el html que te agregue la librería de jquery que uso yo.

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: No funciona, alguna idea de porque?

Comment: agregaste la librería de jquery antes de ejecutar esa función?

Comment: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>` ese es el codigo que agregue

Comment: ahí edite mi respuesta mas acorde a tu problema, fíjate si te sirve eso!

Comment: Si me funciono, como se puede hacer que haga una animación de derecha a izquierda? Osea, como que aparezca desde la derecha de la pantalla y no aparezca asi de una